# Peewee and Database Inheritance

Tags: python, single-table-inheritance, peewee, concrete-inheritance

I'm trying to learn Peewee and Bottle by making a book note-taking application.

Say I have the following entities:

```
Subject
Book
Chapter
Note
Tag
```

I would like to be able to make Notes for Chapters, Books, and Subjects.

In a DB, you would do:

```sql
create table noteable (
    noteable_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (type in ('SUBJECT','BOOK','CHAPTER','NOTE'))
);
create table subject (
    subject_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,noteable_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES noteable (noteable_id)
    ,...
);
create table book (
    book_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,subject_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES subject (subject_id)
    ,noteable_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES noteable (noteable_id)
    ,...
);
create table chapter(
    chapter_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,book_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES book (book_id)
    ,noteable_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES noteable(noteable_id)
    ,...
);

create table note(
    note_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,noteable_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES noteable(noteable_id)
    ,...
);
```

(If you wanted a M:N relationship between note and notable, you would do a note_notable bridge table as well).

You would have before insert triggers on subject, book, and chapter that would insert a row into noteable, retrieve the new row's noteable_id, and use that on the incoming row.

I'm assuming that if you are using an ORM like Peewee you would want to do that in application logic rather than triggers.

*How can I implement this model in Peewee?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I couldn't find a native way in Peewee to implement inheritance so I just rolled it myslef. If there is a better way, please provide your answer and I'll award it.

```
import MySQLdb
import peewee
from peewee import *
from datetime import datetime

db = MySQLDatabase('test', user='root',passwd='psswd')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Noteable(BaseModel):
    type = CharField(null = False)

# This will act as the trigger that inserts a row into noteable,
# and retrieves the notable.id to use
class N(BaseModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            noteable = Noteable(type=self.__class__.__name__.upper())
            noteable.save()
            self.noteable = noteable.id
        return super(N, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Subject(N):
    name = CharField(null = False, unique = True)
    noteable = ForeignKeyField(Noteable, related_name="noteablesubject", null= False, unique = True)


class Book(N):
    name = CharField(null = False, unique = True)
    subject = ForeignKeyField(Subject, related_name="books", null = False)
    noteable = ForeignKeyField(Noteable, related_name="noteablebook", null= False, unique = True)


class Chapter(N):
    name = CharField(null = False)
    chapter_number = IntegerField(null = False)
    book = ForeignKeyField(Book, related_name="chapters")
    noteable = ForeignKeyField(Noteable, related_name="noteablechapter", null= False, unique = True)


class Note(BaseModel):
    note = TextField(null = False)
    # N.B. unique is not true, as multiple notes can go to the same subject/book/chapter
    noteable = ForeignKeyField(Noteable, related_name="notes", null= False)


Note.drop_table(True)
Chapter.drop_table(True)
Book.drop_table(True)
Subject.drop_table(True)
Noteable.drop_table(True)

Noteable.create_table(True)
Subject.create_table(True)
Book.create_table(True)
Chapter.create_table(True)
Note.create_table(True)

s = Subject(name="subject")
s.save()
n = Note(note="subject notes", noteable = s.noteable)
n.save()
n = Note(note="subject notes 2", noteable = s.noteable)
n.save()
b = Book(name="book", subject=s)
b.save()
n = Note(note="book notes", noteable = b.noteable)
n.save()
n = Note(note="book notes 2", noteable = b.noteable)
n.save()
c = Chapter(chapter_number=1, name="chapter", book=b)
c.save()
n = Note(note="chapter notes", noteable=c.noteable)
n.save()
n = Note(note="chapter notes 2", noteable=c.noteable)
n.save()
```

(if you wished to have a many to many relationship between notes and notable, you would have to define a NoteNotable class with foreign keys and remove the FK from Note)

You can define a helper method to left join whichever class with notes:

```
def get_notes(clazz, id):
    return clazz.select().join(Noteable).join(Note, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER).where(clazz.id = id)
```

You can iterate over it like:

```
% for note in chapter.noteable.notes:

% end
```

Here are the results from a `SELECT * FROM NOTABLE;`

```
+----+---------+
| id | type    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | SUBJECT |
|  2 | BOOK    |
|  3 | CHAPTER |
+----+---------+
```

Here are the results from a `SELECT * FROM NOTE;`

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+
| id | note            | noteable_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | subject notes   |           1 |
|  2 | subject notes 2 |           1 |
|  3 | book notes      |           2 |
|  4 | book notes 2    |           2 |
|  5 | chapter notes   |           3 |
|  6 | chapter notes 2 |           3 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
```