# Peewee foreign key from one table to different tabels

Tags: python, peewee

I'm working on simple asset manager database using peewee. Each asset can belong to one of the types: image or video.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
# MAIN ASSET
class Asset(Model):
    name = CharField()
    datetime = DateTimeField()
    miniature = CharField()
    preview = CharField()
    type_ = ForeignKeyField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB

# TYPE SPECIFIC
class Image(Model):
    resolution_x = IntegerField()
    resolution_y = IntegerField()
    channels = CharField()
    layers = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB

class Video(Model):
    resolution_x = IntegerField()
    resolution_y = IntegerField()
    framerate = FloatField()
    bitrate = FloatField()
    duration = FloatField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB
```

I would like to keep all the assets in one table, asset specific fields in other and connect them with "type_" field (ex. using foreign key or something). How can I achieve that? I suppose foreign key is a bad approach since it requires a predetermined model.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I think you're thinking about this backwards. I would just put FK fields on `Image` and `Video` that point to the relevant asset (e.g. `asset = ForeignKeyField(Asset)`)

Comment: This is my "plan b" with few caveats like global searching problem. Convient will be searching throughout Asset table and use FK to connect with specific data for the asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a [Multiple Table Inheritance](https://danchak99.wordpress.com/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582689/peewee-and-database-inheritance) thread could be helpful